# How to change desktop icon text background color in yaru-unity theme?

Tags: unity

Hi on my unity version of ubuntu 18.04 LTS I use the Yaru-Unity theme. However, the icon fonts appear black to me on the desktop. Is there any way to make them white like in the photo?[image]

Comment: Did you install unity on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Yes of course...

Comment: I'm interested in making the desktop icons fonts white as in the attached image.

Comment: is Yaru-unity theme preinstalled or have you downloaded and installed it?

Comment: I installed it by downloading it

Comment: is there a procedure to change the font color of the icons on the desktop?

Comment: I would like to test it. It is possible. But I need to go through how you installed. I will try to install unity n the theme u mentioned.

Comment: in fact I created a hidden folder of themes and icons in the home. there I put Yaru-Unity theme

Comment: I'm interested in changing the font color of the desktop icons. just this. but only on this theme yaru unity theme.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. but it did not work...

Comment: Ok then I shall try now by installing both. Will get back soon.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi, I have installed unity. but not able to install/Download the Yaru unity theme. Can you guide me?

Comment: Certain. the theme is found here. https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1380458

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uctzx.png Hi, I am not able to reproduce this. Point to note, I have tried it in Ubuntu 20.04 as I dont have 18.04 Installed.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt. But it also seems in your case that the characters of the folders are not as white as I would like them

Comment: I think it's a bug with nautilus. I have tried with different themes but none changed the color you are looking for.

Comment: You can be sure. However I managed through this modification .nautilus-desktop.nautilus-canvas-item {
   color: white;
   text-shadow: 1px 1px none;
}
to change it to white. On the other hand, the background of the character that remains black was not successful.

Comment: canvas-item is the main point in the duplicated link too. In your code add { ..; ..; background-color: blue }